# "Variable" cannot be resolved to a variable.?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Car {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> car = new ArrayList<String>();
        car.add("engine");
        car.add("exhaust");
        car.add("wheel");
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++);
        System.out.println(car.get(j));
```

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    j cannot be resolved to a variable***

I am new to Java and really looking up in programming because I would like to program. I am in my A-Levels,at the moment. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the `for` line, and put `{` and `}` around those lines that you want to have repeated in a loop.  The extra semicolon makes the variable `j` go out of scope.

Comment: Because the for should not end with `;` `System.out.println(Auto.get(j));`

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your class below. As noted in the comments above, a semicolon terminates the "for loop" immediately, executing no action whatsoever. Besides, j won't be visible, as its scope is only within the loop iteself, and that's the reason for the error message you're getting.

Unrelated to your question, I have also modified the exit condition for the loop to be `j < 3` to avoid indexing a non-existing j element upon the last iteration (`car.get(3)`).

```
public class Car {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> car = new ArrayList<String>();
    car.add("engine");
    car.add("exhaust");
    car.add("wheel");
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(car.get(j));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a specific close reason for problems that are caused by typographical errors.  We shouldn't be answering questions like this.

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Car {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     ArrayList<String> car = new ArrayList<String>();
     car.add("engine");
     car.add("exhaust");
     car.add("wheel");
     {
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
     System.out.println(car.get(j));
     }
   }
 }

Comment: Is that a typographical error, or a misunderstanding of how statement termination and scopes work?